# Libpcap - Received vs. Sent packets

Tags: c++, c, libpcap

I'm using the libpcap for capturing all packets on a specific port. But I need to separate and know clearly which packets my device is sending, and which ones it is receiving.
Actually I use `pcap_close()` for capturing packets, and it's working well ; but the struct pcap_pkthdr doesn't contain any information if the packet is received or sent.

I have a few options, but I think all of them are not quite good:

- I could try getting my own IP and compare it with the IP inside the `IP Header`, but it's a big heavy to always check my IP and compare it...
- I could do two pcap filter with in one `src host` and the other `dest host`. But that would make no sense to have two filter like this, and I wouldn't know how to capture with two separate filter.

So, am I wrong ? If not, is there an efficient way to separate received from sent packets ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source mac can tell if it is ingress or egress. If packet captured has source Mac of host, it is egress else it is ingress.